# Store values from a variable and reuse them

Tags: matrix, stata

This is a question that could help me to solve another, still unsolved question I posted. Basically I need to condition a dataset in Stata and I thought a procedure which would need to first store certain values of a variable in a sort of matrix and then use compare the values of another variable with those stored in the matrix. A simple example could be the following:

```
obs id act1 act2  year act1year
  1   1   0    1   2000    0
  2   1   1    0   2001   2001
  3   1   0    1   2004    0  
  4   2   1    0   2001   2001
  5   2   1    0   2002   2002
  6   2   0    1   2004    0
```

The code should be able to save in the matrix by(id) the value of `act1year` different from `0` (in this case 2001) for group 1  and then check if this value, for observations for which `act2` is 1, is included in the range for `obs`  i=1,3 [year(i) : year(i)-2] in this case the range does not contain the value stored in the matrix; therefore the observation will be dropped. For group `id` 2  the code should store [2001, 2002] and then check if the range [year(6):year(6)-2] contains any of the values stored in the matrix.

I hope my question is clear enough! Apologies for not posting any attempt but this is something I really have no idea about how to do.

Comment: Cross-reference is to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436776/conditioning-stata-dataset-on-past-values-of-variables

Comment: This is not at all clear. I'd back up and show us a data example and **then** what you want to see in the data after manipulation. The attempt at abstraction here isn't clarifying the question. Although I don't understand what you want, the  idea of using "a sort of matrix" doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: The idea is to find a code that drop observation 3 because act2 is performed more than 2 years later than act1. Observation with act1==1 should not be dropped and observation in which act2==1 follows after no more than 2 years from act1 should be kept as it is the case for observation 6

Comment: You are describing, but not, as requested, "showing" what the resulting data should look like.  Do it by hand, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both this question and the previous discussion are difficult for me to understand, so let me suggest the following as a starting point to a solution that identifies observations for which either (a) act1 occurs or (b) act2 occurs no more than 2 years after the most recent act1 occurrence.

```
clear
input id act1 act2  year
  1   0    1   2000
  1   1    0   2001
  1   0    1   2004
  2   1    0   2001
  2   1    0   2002
  2   0    1   2004
end
generate a1yr = 0
replace  a1yr = year if act1==1
generate act1r = -act1
bysort id (year act1r): replace a1yr=a1yr[_n-1] if a1yr==0 & _n>1
generate tokeep = 0
replace  tokeep = 1 if act1==1
replace  tokeep = 1 if act2==1 & year-a1yr<=2
list, clean noobs
```

Looking at the previous discussion, as it now stands, suggests substituting the following data into the code above and seeing if the code then meets the needs of that discussion.

```
input obsno id act1 act2  year
  1  1  1 0 2000
  2  1  0 1 2001
  3  1  0 1 2002
  4  1  0 1 2002
  5  1  0 1 2003
  6  2  1 0 2000
  7  2  1 0 2001
  8  2  0 1 2002
  9  2  0 1 2002
 10  2  0 1 2003
end
```

Comment: That's an amazing piece of code which solves both questions. Thank you a lot!